# Arduino sketch works on ATmega1280, but doesn't work on ATmega328 (Arduino Nano)

Tags: led, bluetooth, android, sram

I'm working on arduino based RGB LED strip controller.
This simple schematic was used to control 12V channels via 5V PWM signal from arduino:
[image: https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/002/692/medium800/led_strips_ledstripfet.gif?1396785823]
I have also connected an HC-05 bluetooth module to be able to control it using android phone.
Android application, created for this project, is sending 4 bytes to set mode, red, green and blue colors. It looks like {0,255,0,0} to set static red color, {1,0,0,0} to start fade mode and {2,0,0,0} to start blink mode.

Here is my first demo video of this project:
[click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UuVex4Qkn8).

The problem is that my code works perfectly on Arduino Mega 1280, but when I use Arduino Nano it works only with manual mode and blink mode. If I send {1,0,0,0} to turn on fade mode, LED strip starts to increase random color brightness and stops, before it gets to max value. In a moment LED strip turns off and doesn't react to bluetooth commands. Reset button helps in this situation.

I'm not sure, but I think there is not enough SRAM (only 2KB) on Arduino Nano to process fade mode data.

**Source code:**

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 13);

#define REDPIN 6
#define GREENPIN 3
#define BLUEPIN 9

#define FADESPEED 10
#define PANICSPEED 425

//0 - red
//1 - green
//2 - blue
int fadeColor = 0;
int panicColor = 0;

//values (brightness) for red, green and blue colors [0; 255]
int colors[] = {0, 0, 0};

long previousTime = 0;

//0 - manual, 1 - fade, 2 - blink
int ledMode = 0;

int fadeAmount = 1;

//if color is selected, it'll change brightness;
//when we got 0 or 255 brightness we'll change
//this flag and select next color in loop()
boolean fadeColorSelected = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(REDPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREENPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUEPIN, OUTPUT);
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  randomSeed(0);
}

void loop() {
  long currentTime = millis();

  //data format - 4 bytes {mode, red, green, blue}
  if (mySerial.available() > 3) {
    ledMode = mySerial.read();
    int red = mySerial.read();
    int green = mySerial.read();
    int blue = mySerial.read();
    colors[0] = constrain(red, 0, 255);
    colors[1] = constrain(green, 0, 255);
    colors[2] = constrain(blue, 0, 255);
  }

  switch (ledMode) {
    //manual mode - just set received color on the led strip
    case 0:
      setColor();
      break;
    //fade mode - if color is selected, we'll 
    //increase/decrease it's brightness by fadeAmount
    case 1:
      if (currentTime - previousTime > FADESPEED) {
        //change color (we can't choose the same color as previous 
        //and we can't choose the color, if it's the last one,
        //because at least 1 color should be always ON
        if (!fadeColorSelected) {
          int randomColor = fadeColor;
          while (randomColor == fadeColor || isColorAlone(randomColor)) {
            randomColor = random(3);
          }
          fadeColor = randomColor;
          fadeColorSelected = true;
        }
        //depending on current brightness of selected color
        //we'll either increase, or decrease it's brightness
        if (colors[fadeColor] == 0) {
          fadeAmount = abs(fadeAmount);
        } else if (colors[fadeColor] == 255) {
          fadeAmount = -abs(fadeAmount);
        }
        colors[fadeColor] += fadeAmount;
        setColor();
        //when we got to max/min brightness, we should change current fadeColor
        if (colors[fadeColor] == 0 || colors[fadeColor] == 255) {
          fadeColorSelected = false;
        }
        previousTime = currentTime;
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (currentTime - previousTime > PANICSPEED) {
        int randomColor = panicColor;
        while (randomColor == panicColor || isColorAlone(randomColor)) {
          randomColor = random(3);
        }
        panicColor = randomColor;
        if (colors[panicColor] == 0) {
          colors[panicColor] = 255;
        } else {
          colors[panicColor] = 0;
        }
        setColor();
        previousTime = currentTime;
      }
      break;
  }
}

void setColor(int r, int g, int b) {
  analogWrite(REDPIN, r);
  analogWrite(GREENPIN, g);
  analogWrite(BLUEPIN, b);
}

void setColor() {
  analogWrite(REDPIN, colors[0]);
  analogWrite(GREENPIN, colors[1]);
  analogWrite(BLUEPIN, colors[2]);
}

boolean isColorAlone(int colorNumber) {
  if (colors[colorNumber] == 0)
    return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i != colorNumber && colors[i] > 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Do you have any ideas why it happens?

If there is not enough SRAM, how can I optimize this code to solve the problem?

Comment: `avr-size` on the ELF says?

Comment: text 4770, data 22, bss 122, dec 4914, hex 1332

Comment: (data + bss) is less than 2KB, but it does not include dynamic memory allocated from the heap at run time...

Comment: You don't have any heap allocation. And I certainly don't see more than about 40 bytes in locals from the stack at any time.

Comment: I agree with you, but I have no idea, what can be wrong with it

Comment: Pin 13 has the Led on it. SoftwareSerial often runs better when using pins with interrupts. On the Uno that is Pin 2 and 3. I also find softwareSerial can be unreliable especially as low and high speed. So try the Uno on pin 2 and 3 and if possible use 19k or 56k which are usually reliable